# How can a Firefox extension get its own version number programmatically?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

**How do I programatically get my own Firefox extension's version number with Javascript?**

My extension has an install.rdf file containing the version number similar to below. I want to extract the contents of the `<em:version>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
 xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    ...
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    ...
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not got the full answer, but I found [the Extended extension](http://extended.spanglerco.com/) and had a look at the source code as it seemed like a good starting point, and from Googling some of the methods in that I found [this snippet on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/On_page_load#Running_code_on_an_extension%27s_first_run_or_after_an_extension%27s_update).  The key bit of code would seem to be this:

```
var gExtensionManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
                        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
var current = gExtensionManager.getItemForID("extension@guid.net").version;
```

You would have to replace `extension@guid.net` with the appropriate ID for your extension.

Firefox 4 requires different code, see the other answer.

Comment: Excellent. That is a full answer! I did have to initialise my own gExtensionManager object.

Comment: Well it wasn't a full answer because I wasn't actually sure it would work :)

Comment: I don't know of any advantage to doing it one way or the other but this is even shorter: `let version = Application.extensions.get('extension@id').version;` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965310/detecting-firefox-extension-version)

Comment: @MatrixFrom: the FUEL API you mention has also changed in Firefox 4, because AddonManager API is now asynchronous. So no benefit to it, other than saving a few bytes in exchange for using a less-tested and less well-known API.

Answer (score 12):

In Firefox 4 (Gecko 2) the API has changed, so if you need to port to Firefox 4, this is the code (from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Retrieving_the_version_of_an_extension_as_specified_in_the_extension%27s_install.rdf)):

```
try {
    // Firefox 4 and later; Mozilla 2 and later
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
    AddonManager.getAddonByID("extension-guid@example.org", function(addon) {
        alert("My extension's version is " + addon.version);
  });
}
catch (ex) {
    // Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before
    var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
             .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
    var addon = em.getItemForID("extension-guid@example.org");
    alert("My extension's version is " + addon.version);
}
```

Comment: Big change is that the Firefox 4 API is asynchronized, while Firefox 3 API is synchronized. If you need blocking, put dependent code in the callback.

Comment: @Crend King: that's true and an imperfect workaround is to save the version number somewhere inside the extension when the extension starts up and retrieve in synchronous manner when you need it. Asynchronous calls are really infectious.

Comment: Version should work fine with your approach, since it is a property of the extension. However, when you try to get user-related information such as extension's installed location, you cannot bypass AddonManager ("ProfD/extensions/<extension_ID>" is not always correct).

Comment: Alternative way to emulate synchronous call is to use [`nsIThread.processNextEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThread#processNextEvent%28%29). [`nsIThreadManager.currentThread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThreadManager#Attributes) is the right thread.

Answer (score 1):

With Add-on SDK its simple as:

`var version = require("sdk/self").version;`

Answer (score 1):

In **Web Extensions** use the following:

```
browser.runtime.getManifest().version
```