# Detecting Firefox extension version

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I have a Firefox Extension that I would like to populate the About box with the version within install.rdf.

I know that FUEL's extIExtension allows one to see the version for an extension but I did not create the extension using FUEL (and the docs on MDC seem very light on how to transition to it). Is there a way to dynamically check the extension version?

I specifically do not want to hard code or make it generated from my Makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sdwilsh, you're right, my apologizes.

Took me awhile to realize the only FUEL object I have access to is fuelApplication, but it looks like this does it:

```
let version = Application.extensions.get('extension@id').version;
```

Answer (score 0):

FUEL is just an API, so it doesn't matter how you implemented your add-on.