# How to get my extension's id from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, I need to get my extension's id in my code, so I don't need to change it manually every time. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't believe the extension's id changes once it's installed? Even when installing it "unpacked" for dev purposes, it keeps the same id unless you uninstall and re-install, no?

Comment: When I develop it, I got id1, when I publish it, I got id2, they're different..

Comment: Why do you need to get the ID?

Comment: @Adam Heath because I want to open chrome://{extension-id}/index.html when the button is clicked

Comment: @AdamHeath Im surprised by your question? "Why do you need to get the ID?". 
There may be many purposes where you need to get the chrome extension id, and yes it is different while in local development and while publishing it. I mean no offence, you can use without id also, but it is good to know.

Comment: @Yegya wow this is an old question! I was asking as if they wanted to link to a page within the extension a relative path would likely work without need for the ID. So there may have been a better solution than getting the ID.

Comment: I thought to use it for security:
 `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse) => { if ( sender.id == chrome.runtime.id ) {//good}else{//bad}});` ... in the background.js

Comment: Run `location.href` from the background script of your extension.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can get it like this (no extra permissions required) in two different ways:

1. Using runtime api: `var myid = chrome.runtime.id;`
2. Using i18n api: `var myid = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id");`

but you don't need it for opening pages, as `chrome.tabs.create()` (and some others) understand relative paths.

So to open `index.html` from your extension folder you should just use:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "index.html"});
```

Comment: Where did you learned about `chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id");`?!? :)

Comment: @JohnS See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/i18n.html#overview-predefined

Comment: Use [`chrome.runtime.id`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-id).

Comment: Does `chrome.runtime.id` only work from the background page? I'm trying to use it and it doesn't work from the normal pages.

Comment: i am using var myid = chrome.runtime.id; but it show me undefined. please help me.

Comment: Another method is to run `location.href` from the background script of your extension.

Answer (score 16):

In WebExtensions, you have two options:

1. `chrome.runtime.id`
2. `chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id")`

In Chrome and Opera, they will return the same value, but in Firefox there is a difference.

In Firefox, `chrome.runtime.id` will return the so called "Extension ID", but `chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id")` will return the "Internal UUID". The extension ID is the same for all users, but the internal UUID is created when the extension is installed and is unique per user.

Depending on the context, the extension ID will not be what you want. For example, Firefox uses the internal UUID to fill the `origin` header, not the extension ID.

**Example 1: Ghostery in Firefox 61**

```
chrome.runtime.id                        --> "firefox@ghostery.com"
chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id") --> "e3225586-81a0-47c3-8612-d95fb0c2a609"
```

For `fetch` requests from within the extension, Firefox will add the header

```
origin: moz-extension://e3225586-81a0-47c3-8612-d95fb0c2a609
```

**Example 2: Ghostery in Chrome**

```
chrome.runtime.id                        --> "mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij"
chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id") --> "mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij"
```

For `fetch` requests from within the extension, Chrome will add the header

```
origin: chrome-extension://mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're doing stuff with localization, it looks like the extension mechanics offer some [placeholders](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html#overview-predefined) for accessing your extension ID:

If you're just trying to access URLs for local files to your extension, you can just use `chrome.extension.getURL("some file name");`

If you have another reason for actually needing to know the id of the extension, I'm not sure there is a straight forward way of getting it from within the extension itself. The two ways that come to me off the top of my head are using `chrome.extension.getURL("some file name")` and then parsing out the extension id from that returned URL - or using [`chrome.management.getAll()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html) and looping through all the installed extensions until you find yours using a match on `name` and then accessing the `id`: